# How to search Parent documents along with count of associated child documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for a best way to search parent documents along with counts for associated child document?  **Example :** 
We have Organization documents and User documents.  There could be thousands of users belong to one particular organization.

Organization document :

```
{
   "id" : "001"
   "name" : "orgname1"
}
{
   "id" : "002"
   "name" : "orgname2"
}
```

Users documents :

```
{
   "id" : "testusr1"
   "name" : "xyz1"
   "orgId" : "001"
},
{
   "id" : "testusr2"
   "name" : "xyz2"
   "orgId" : "001"
}
{
   "id" : "testusr3"
   "name" : "xyz3"
   "orgId" : "001"
}
{
   "id" : "testusr4"
   "name" : "xyz4"
   "orgId" : "001"
}
{
   "id" : "testusr5"
   "name" : "xyz5"
   "orgId" : "002"
}
{
   "id" : "testusr6"
   "name" : "xyz6"
   "orgId" : "002"
}
```

In above example, we have 4 users associated with organization with 001 and 2 users associated with 002.  So on front end, admin will search for organization and as a result, I want to give response along with users count for that organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve you issue in three ways. Each have its own advantages and disadvantages

**1. Index Parent and child separately**

This will require two queries . First you need to query user index and get orgId and then query child index and get its count

Advantage.

Change in one index doesn't affect other index

Disadvantage .

You need to use two queries

**2. [Nested Documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)**

Mapping:

```
PUT index9
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id":{
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "name":{
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword":{
            "type":"keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "user":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
              "keyword":{
              "type":"keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "name":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
              "keyword":{
              "type":"keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


POST index9/_doc
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "orgname1",
  "user":[
           {
             "id":"testuser1",
             "name":"xyz1"
           },
           {
             "id":"testuser2",
             "name":"xyz2"
           }
         ]
}
```

Query:

```
GET index9/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "organization": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "user": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "user"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "user.id.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "organization" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 1,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "user" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "count" : {
              "value" : 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Nested are faster compared to parent/child,
Nested docs require reindexing the parent with all its children, while parent child allows to reindex / add / delete specific children.

**3. [Parent Child Relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html)**

Mapping

```
{
  "my_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "my_join_field" : {
          "type" : "join",
          "eager_global_ordinals" : true,
          "relations" : {
            "organization" : "user"
          }
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "orgId" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Data:

```
POST my_index/_doc/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "name" : "orgname1",
  "my_join_field": "organization" 
}

POST my_index/_doc/2
{
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "orgname2",
  "my_join_field": "organization" 
}

POST my_index/_doc/3?routing=1
{
  "id": "testusr1",
  "name": "xyz1",
  "orgId": 1,
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "user",
    "parent": 1
  }
}

POST my_index/_doc/4?routing=2
{
   "id" : "testusr5",
   "name" : "xyz5",
   "orgId" : 1,
   "my_join_field": {
    "name": "user",
    "parent": 2
  }
}

POST my_index/_doc/5?routing=2
{
   "id" : "testusr6",
   "name" : "xyz6",
   "orgId" : 2,
   "my_join_field": {
    "name": "user",
    "parent": 2
  }
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "user",
      "query": { "match_all": {} }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "organization": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "user": {
          "children": {
            "type": "user"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "id"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "name" : "orgname1",
          "my_join_field" : "organization"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2,
          "name" : "orgname2",
          "my_join_field" : "organization"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "organization" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "user" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "count" : {
              "value" : 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "2",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "user" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "count" : {
              "value" : 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Benefits:
   1. Parent document and children are separate documents

2. Parent and child can be updated separately without re-indexing the other
3. It is useful when child documents are large in number and need to be added or 
     changed frequently.
4. Child documents can be returned as the results of a search request.

Comment: Thank you so much for you great answers to this question. I would like to go with option #1.

Comment: Glad could be of help.